# How can I define operators so that a array of user-defined types can be transformed into an array of primitive types?

Tags: c++, containers, implicit-conversion

I give the following code to illustrate my question:

```
#include <vector>

struct Complex
{
     int a, b, c;

     Complex() : a(3), b(4), c(10) {}

     operator int() const {  return a+b+c; }
};

int main()
{
   Complex abc;
   int value = (abc);
   Complex def;
   def.a = 20;
   int value2 = (def);

   std::vector<Complex> ar;
   ar.push_back(abc);
   ar.push_back(def);

   std::vector<int> ar2;
   ar2.push_back(abc);
   ar2.push_back(def);

   std::vector<int> ar3;
   ar3 = (ar);
}
```

This won't compile, due to the expression `ar3 = (ar)`. I have declared a conversion operator so that the `Complex` class can be used in where `int` is expected.  Can I also make it work for assigning an array of `Complex` objects to an array of `int`?

I tried to declare a non-member conversion operator for array of `Complex`, but that's not allowed:

```
void std::vector<int> operator = (std::vector<Complex> complexArray)
{
    std::vector<int> abc;
    for(int i=0; i<complexArray.size(); i++)
     abc.push_back(complexArray[i]);
    return abc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about automatic implicit conversion (at least for the Standard Library containers). But if you are willing to accept an explicit conversion like in the below example

```
 const std::vector<int> vi {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 const std::vector<double> vd = container_cast(vi);
```

then the implementation of the `container_cast()` utility follows. Note that it can cast not only between instantiations of the same template container for different element types (i.e. `std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<double>`), but also between different containers (e.g. `std::vector` to `std::list`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<class SourceContainer>
class ContainerConverter
{
    const SourceContainer& s_;
public:
    explicit ContainerConverter(const SourceContainer& s) : s_(s) {}

    template<class TargetContainer>
    operator TargetContainer() const
    {
        return TargetContainer(s_.begin(), s_.end());
    }
};

template<class C>
ContainerConverter<C> container_cast(const C& c)
{
    return ContainerConverter<C>(c);
}

template<class C>
void printContainer(const C& c)
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for( auto x : c )
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<double> vd {2.2, 7.7, 5.5, 1.1, -4.4};
    printContainer(vd);

    const std::vector<int> vi = container_cast(vd);
    printContainer(vi);

    const std::list<float> lf = container_cast(vd);
    printContainer(lf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may consider the range constructor of `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> ar3(begin(ar), end(ar));
```

Comment: You'll also need `using std::begin; using std::end;` if you want the argument-dependent lookup to include the usual functions.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to transform something, the [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) function might be good to use.

In your case you could do something like

```
// Create the new vector with the same size as the complex vector
std::vector<int> abc(complexArray.size());

std::transform(std::begin(complexVector), std::end(complexVector),
               std::begin(abc),
               [](Complex const& complex)
               {
                   int result;

                   // Code here that converts the complex structure to an integer
                   // and stores the integer in the variable result

                   return result;
               });
```

After the [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) call above (once you complete it with the code to actually do the structure transformation) the vector `abc` will contain all the converted integers from the `Complex` structures in the source vector `complexVector`.