# Copying vector<shared_pt<T>> to vector<shared_ptr<const T>> (different cases) C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>
```

Which I would like to copy to a

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>
```

Now I noticed that if I do this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>& list) : internalList(list.begin(), list.end()) {}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>> internalList;
};
```

it compiles fine (clang++ std==c++14) but if I do:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>& list) : internalList(list) {}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>> internalList;
};
```

I find it strange that when I use a copy constructor it doesn't work because it can't figure out the conversion from non-const to const?

```
xxxx.cpp:672:56: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int> >'
```

Could someone explain why please, and if the way I do it (using iterator in the constructor) is the best solution?

Comment: It would be fine if it was *just* a conversion from non-const to const (i.e. `int` to `const int`). However that's not what's happening here, it's a conversion from an object of one type to an object of a completely different type. And a copy-constructor only takes its own type as the argument, not a different type.

Comment: Okay it makes sense but wouldn't something like this work?  `int a = 1; const int b = a`? So my question is why is this assignment working and why can't this be done using the copy constructor? I am really curious what stops it from doing this? I assume it's not done for optimisation reasons...

Comment: @user18490 `const std::vector<T>` is not the same as `std::vector<const T>`. Hence the analogy to `int` and `const int` doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first the class template instantiated with different types are totally different type at all. Then `std::shared_ptr<int>` and `std::shared_ptr<const int>` are totally different types, and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>>` are different types too, and can't be converted to each other.

According to the [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector`, the copy constructor (the 5th one) takes a `std::vector` with same type as its parameter. It means for `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>>`, it can't takes `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>`, which can't be converted to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>>` implicitly.

On the other hand the constructor taking iterator range (the 4th one) is function template, the type of the iterator is template parameter, which doesn't have to be the iterator pointing to the same type. It's allowed to be iterator pointing to other type, if this type could be used to construct the vector. `std::shared_ptr<int>` could be used to construct `std::shared_ptr<const int>`, then it's fine.

Note that [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) have copy/move constructor templates which could take `std::shared_ptr` with different element type as its argument. (While `std::vector` doesn't.)

Answer (score 3):

Your code could work if `std::vector` provided a converting constructor:

```
template<class T, class A = std::allocator<T>>
class vector {
public:
    template<class T1, class A1>
    explicit vector(const vector<T1, A1>& other)
        : vector(other.begin(), other.end())
    {}

    ...
};
```

But having such a constructor in every Standard Library container doesn't add too much value, because almost the same effect can be achieved by introducing an even more general purpose `container_cast` utility (see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304806/6394138)). Then you could write:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>& list) : internalList(container_cast(list)) {}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const int>> internalList;
};
```

Comment: Note that that `container_cast` implementation forces copies and never moves, an improvement needed before using it in real code. ;-]